# What does construction s() stand for in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have a piece of example code in Prolog. I wonder what the predicate/rule/functor **s()** means in Prolog? (on line that starts with **breadth_search**). I did not see any declaration of this construction above example code. It might be a system predicate. Who knows?

```
main(Decision) :-
     initial_state(State),
     breadth_search([s(State,[])],[],[],Decision),
     writeln(Decision).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just stands "for itself".

`s(State,[])`

is just a structure/graph (a "term"), in fact a tree, with:

- a node labeled `s` as root
- two arguments

  - whatever is designated by the variable name `State` as arg1 (which may be an "empty cell" if that variable is unbound)
  - a special constant denoting the empty list as arg2 (depending on the implementations, this may or may not be a "null pointer"; in SWI-Prolog it is a special "atomic" term, which is the correct implementation decision IMHO)

```
        s
        |
   +----+----+
   |         |
 State       []
```

Comment: Why it's needed? and what is the full name of s()?

Comment: `s` can be anything. You can build a structure with `foo` at the root: `foo(bar,baz)`. Consider it as the declaration + initialization of an object.

Comment: @NickReshetinsky Note that the structure acquires meaning depending on how you use it. For example, if there is a predicate `s/2` somewhere (i.e. named `s` with two arguments), you can _call_ it: `call(s(State,[]))`

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> "I did not see any declaration of this construction above example code."

Why there should be any? Prolog is not an [*expression oriented* language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression-oriented_programming_language). Prolog's predicates do not *evaluate* their arguments. Everything is symbolic. Every piece of data is symbolic. It does not get evaluated. It stays as it is.

In particular, some Prolog's terms fall in the category of *"compound"* terms. They have a label, -- a *"functor"* in Prolog parlance, -- and some number of *"arguments"*. Seeing is believing, so

```
a_functor( arg1, arg2, arg3 )
```

is a compound term, of *"arity"* *3* (a.k.a. "ternary" term), with three arguments and a functor `a_functor`. Functors must be simple atoms, arguments may be any valid Prolog term, including logical variables.

Thus,

```
s(State,[])
```

is another example of a compound term, of arity *2* (a.k.a. "binary" term), with the functor `s` (a simple atom), and two arguments, a logical variable `State`, and a term `[]`.

This is all.

Comment: We should have had more of these languages at school! Thinking in terms of "everything is compiled to some binary mess before being manipulated" forecloses a lot of possibilities.